# Detecting remote desktop connection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there anyway, in a program, to detect if a program is being run from inside a remote desktop session or if the program is being run normal in .NET 2.0? What I'm trying to do is, I create a timeclock application which will clock a person in and out and keep track. But this particular person, I suspect, is remoting into their computer at work, from home, and clocking in and out.

Any ideas how I can solve this issue (and taking away remote desktop access is not an option)? My idea is, if there is a way to detect remote desktop sessions, I will simply implement this into the progam and prevent them from clocking in remotely.

Comment: Ha ha, that's an interesting problem :)

Comment: One problem here will be the range of different remote tools - MSTSC and VNC will be big contenders, but what about PCAnywhere, Live Mesh, GoToMyPC etc, not to mention things like Live Meeting and Adobe Connect Pro, which can both do desktop remoting. To do robustly, this could be very hard.

Comment: sorry to ask... i know it's out of topic.
But client to client connected through different networks using RDP is it versatile?

Answer (score 57):

allegedly,

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession
```

will be true for a remote desktop session (or VNC session)

but i'd test it to be sure ;-)

Comment: I highly doubt this will pick up VNC sessions. It will probably detect RDP.

Comment: I've checked, and (unlike %sessionname% - other answer) this works fine even with the /console or /admin switch. This sounds like the best answer for MSTSC.

Comment: Good VNC servers plug into the graphics driver to improve performance.  It might be possible to detect that.

Comment: Works great with Windows Remote Desktop.

Comment: @MarkRichman You'd need to reference Windows.Forms but it should work

Comment: seems to work fine until two weeks ago... perhaps some windows update?

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll just for this (as suggested above), then you can also call the underlying system call directly via PInvoke, like this:

```
    int result = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_REMOTESESSION);
    bool isRemoteSession = (result != 0);
```

The SystemMetric enumeration can be found at [PInvoke.net - SystemMetric](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.SystemMetric) (but you can just use the value of 0x1000); while the signature for GetSystemMetrics at [PInvoke.net - GetSystemMetrics](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getsystemmetrics).

I tested this with RDP and VNC - works with the former (admin/console mode also), does not detect the latter.

Answer (score 13):

For Windows Store apps, you can use this:

```
Windows.System.RemoteDesktop.InteractiveSession.IsRemote
```

Comment: Works with Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

http://www.appdeploy.com/messageboards/tm.asp?m=21420&mpage=1&key=&#21420

The system variable %sessionname% will return Console if its local or RDP* if its remote.

```
isRDP = [System.Environment]
    .GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME").StartsWith("RDP-")
```

Comment: If you RDP with the /console switch (or /admin, depending on the version), then it returns "Console" (I've just checked ;-p)

Comment: System.Environment..GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME").StartsWith("RDP-"); Worked for me.

Comment: Its returns Console on RDP for me.

Answer (score 9):

For WPF applications [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotesession?view=netframework-4.7.2) 
`System.Windows.SystemParameters.IsRemoteSession` [and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotelycontrolled?view=netframework-4.7.2) `System.Windows.SystemParameters.IsRemotelyControlled`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I had a similar issue a few days ago. What I did to resolve it was took advantage of the fact that some **Remote Desktop Application** use a known **default port**, at least **VNC** and/or **Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection**. So I created a method which tells if the port is being used, as follows:

```
/* Libraries needed */
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

/*....
  ....
  ....*/

private static bool IsPortBeingUsed(int port)
{
    return IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().
                GetActiveTcpConnections().
                    Any(
                            tcpConnectionInformation => 
                            tcpConnectionInformation.LocalEndPoint.Port == port
                       );
}
```

Remember to put the using statements with the libraries at the beginning of the file where the method is.

You just have to pass for example a parameter like the **3389 port** which is the default port for **Remote Desktop Connection**, or the **5900 port** which is the default port for **VNC Connections**.

The method is created with **C# 4.0** features but it can perfectly be done with and older version of **C#.Net or Visual Basic.**

This worked for me since I only needed to check for the two application I mentioned before.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 3):

All remote login programs require a service or program running on the local machine. The questioner only needs to worry about VNC and its clones if those services or programs are allowed to run on his local machine. They are not necessary for Remote Desktop use, and there are Remote Desktop clients for all operating systems. A VNC server is unnecessary if Remote Desktop is working.

Furthermore, the VNC clones can't log in for you unless you install them as an administrator on the server machine. As long as you don't let users run processes as other users, the only concern is if  one of your other employees is logging in as the problematic one. And if that's the case, no technical solution is going to be sufficient. Even if you have individual cards for each employee that must be used to log in, the problematic employee could just give his friend the card.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note to say that using GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_REMOTESESSION) on its own has stopped being reliable for Windows 8 / Server 2012 onwards if the session is using RemoteFX virtualisation of the GPU.

The "official" method of detecting RDS is described by Microsoft here: [Detecting the Remote Desktop Services environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/detecting-the-terminal-services-environment)  (Last updated 31 May 18).

It consists of using the SystemMetrics call **and** a registry check at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\GlassSessionId
```

The code samples in that article are C++ only, but given that it's just a registry lookup, I don't think folks will find it too tricksty to replicate in other languages.

I'd like to hope that at least some of the .Net built in functions mentioned upthread are following this in full, but :

- SystemParameters.IsRemoteSession is [noted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotesession?view=netframework-4.7.2) as "Maps to SM_REMOTESESSION. See GetSystemMetrics", and
- SystemParameters.IsRemotelyControlled is [noted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotelycontrolled?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the same,

so I'm not optimistic.

I'll try to do some detailed checks shortly and post the results.

Comment: This seems to be the answer , read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/detecting-the-terminal-services-environment

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about VNC, it looks like it would be possible to check open TCP connections with `netstat`. In a command prompt, type:

```
netstat -n -a -p tcp
```

and check to see if the port 5900 is "ESTABLISHED". Of course, 5900 is the default connection port, so it would be dependent on what port is set.

From there, I found [this post at CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=241826) that explains how to use `netstat` in your c# program:

```
string sCommand = "netstat";
string sArgs = "";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo (sCommand, sArgs);

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandartOutput = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = null;
proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
proc.WaitForExit();

// Read the first 4 lines. They don't contain any information we need to get
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    string strLine = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    if (strLine == null)
        break;

    // Analyze the line 
    // Line is in following structure:
    // Protocol (TCP/UDP)   Local Address(host:port) Foreign Address(host:port) State(ESTABLISHED, ...)
}
```

Comment: A small note: looks like the code snippet posted at CodeGuru has a bit of a spelling error in it, in that `StandardOutput` is misspelled as `StandartOutput`