# C# check RDP user login

Tags: c#, rdp

I'm writing C# program that used on desktop or server os. And I need to know that the current user is working via RDP. How can I get this information?

Comment: You may be able to get some ideas here - but this will mean creating your own interfaces to these ideas: http://superuser.com/questions/528737/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-user-logged-in-via-remote-desktop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting remote desktop connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973802/detecting-remote-desktop-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system variable %sessionname% will return Console if its local or RDP* if its remote.

```
isRDP = [System.Environment]
    .GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME").StartsWith("RDP-")
```

Comment: it always return null string