# SystemParameters.IsRemotelyControlled always false

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I have some code in a standard WPF program in which I want to know whether the computer on which my program runs is remote controlled.

For this I use [SystemParameters.IsRemoteControlled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotelycontrolled?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_SystemParameters_IsRemotelyControlled) as was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973802/detecting-remote-desktop-connection).

> SystemParameters.IsRemoteControlled: true if the current session is remotely controlled;
> otherwise, false.
> This system metric is used in a Terminal Services environment.
> Maps to SM_REMOTECONTROL. See GetSystemMetrics.

```
private bool IsRemoteControlled => SystemParameter.IsRemoteControlled();
```

Alas, if I start my program while I use Remote Desktop or TeamViewer to control the program, the value is false, even if I run the program on a computer without a monitor.

Using [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) in a console program, doesn't help, I still get false.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isRemoteControlled = GetIsRemoteControlled();
    Console.WriteLine(isRemoteControlled);
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric smIndex);

private static bool GetTerminalServerSession()
{
    const int SM_REMOTECONTROL = 0x2001;
    int result = GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTECONTROL);
    bool isRemoteSession = (result != 0);
    return isRemoteSession;
}
```

So how do I know whether the computer is remote controlled, using remote desktop, and preferably using any remote control program. What event is associated with the value change?

Comment: Note that the documentation clearly says that "This system metric is used  in a Terminal Services environment." Neither Remote Desktop nor TeamViewer are using Terminal Services.

Comment: `SM_REMOTESESSION` will work if you want to detect Remote Desktop; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/detecting-the-terminal-services-environment