# DataGridView CellFormatting event preventing form painting

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, paint

I am using C#, Winforms, and .Net 3.5

My form has a custom `DataGridView` (double-buffered to prevent flickering during my cellformatting events, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)). When I perform a database search, I bind the resulting dataset to the `datagridview`.

I handle the `CellFormatting` event to paint rows a certain color, depending on their data.

My DataGridView code:

```
resultsGridView.DataSource = results.DefaultViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0];
resultsGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
resultsGridView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
resultsGridView.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(resultsGridView_CellFormatting);
```

My CellFormatting code:

```
void resultsGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow therow = resultsGridView.Rows[rowIndex];
    if ((bool)therow.Cells["Sealed"].Value == true)
    {
        therow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
    if (therow.Cells["Database"].Value as string == "PNG")
    {
        therow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
}
```

Everything works great except that, when I handle the CellFormatting, the whole form's Paint event seems to be turned off. The cursor stops blinking in the textbox, and the form's menustrip looks like this:

[image: Menu bar picture]

The top is before a search, the bottom after. The menubar won't redraw until I mouse over where the menuitems are, and then the last item to be highlighted will stay that way when I move the mouse out of the menubar. Moving the form seems to cause it to repaint, but then the problem remains.

Commenting out the `resultsGridView.CellFormatting` line in the datagridview code completely fixes the problem.

Am I painting the cells wrong, or is there something else I need to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably causing an exception inside this event. I'm not sure how the handling is defined, but surrounding the code with a try catch would be a first step.

```
try 
{
   int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
   ....   
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Error(ex.message);
}
```

On a second look, I don't think `therow.Cells["Sealed"]` will work. Try something like `therow.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"]`. Cells is indexed by **Column Name**, not **DataPropertyName**.

Comment: The "Sealed" part is not the data property, but rather a bool condition in my database. The program I'm working on does a search on a name and can show whether our case file in the department has been sealed or not.

Comment: No exceptions to catch. I added `Systems.Diagnotics.Trace.WriteLine("start")` at the beginning of the formatting event, and it's running a LOT, even after the cells have been displayed and nothing else is going on.

Comment: But is "Sealed" the name of a Dgv Column object?

Comment: And I think you should set `e.CellStyle.BackColor`, not  `theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`.

Comment: You got it - changing how the cells were being painted was the trick. Changing to `e.CellStyle.BackColor` fixes it.

Comment: And yes, "sealed" is the name of the column in the database, and in the datagridview (which is bound)

Comment: Maybe you should read the part about Sealed again - the database name is irrelevant here, it is about the component.