# How to improve painting performance of DataGridView?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, repaint, paint

(sorry for bad English)

I have a **big** problem with performance of `DataGridView` when it re-paints.

I'm using a `DataGridView` to show logs from an external application stream. Messages from the stream come in with a high frequency (less than 1 ms). If I add new row to the `DataGridView` immediately when each new message comes, the `DataGridView` doesn't have time to re-paint itself before the next message comes.

A possible solution is to use a queue to collect messages and re-paint `DataGridView` every 100 ms with messages from queue. This is good but the `DataGridView` blinks when it auto-scrolls to the last row. (Smooth scroll is disabled)

Can you help me to improve `DataGridView` performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horrible redraw performance of the DataGridView on one of my two screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I recently had some slowness issues with `DataGridView` and the solution was the following code

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
{
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
          BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
}
```

It turns double buffering on for `DataGridView` objects. Just call `DoubleBuffered()` on your DGV. Hope it helps.

**Edit:** I might've gotten this off SO, but I can't search for the original right now so this is just to emphasize that the code isn't mine.

Comment: The method you posted uses reflection to change a non-public property on a `DataGridView` control. This is an acceptable solution, but it's probably cleaner just to inherit off of the existing `DataGridView` control and create your own custom control with the "DoubleBuffered" style set.

Comment: My problem is that if I derive my own control then the form in the editor won't display.

Answer (score 9):

Have you enabled double buffering for the grid view?

have a look at
[Horrible redraw performance of the DataGridView on one of my two screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)

if you haven't already for some ideas

Answer (score 7):

Clean Solution without reflection is:

```
public class DataGridViewDoubleBuffered : DataGridView
{
   public DataGridViewDoubleBuffered()
   {
       DoubleBuffered = true;
   }
}
```

Then go to myForm.designer.cs and change a type from DataGridView to DataGridViewDoubleBuffered .

Comment: And if you expand MyForm.cs in the Solution Explorer, you can open MyForm.Designer.cs and make it instantiate the double buffered subclass instead of the base class.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's night and day different. To anyone wondering how to do this - add this class to the bottom of your code - I added it within my namespace outside of my form class. Then, open your form's `Designer.CS` (`Form1.Designer.cs`) and click the `+` sign next to `Windows Form Designer generated code` to unhide the section. Change the datagridview initialization (something like `this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`) - change it to `this.dataGridView1 = new DataGridViewDoubleBuffered`. Then, scroll down to the bottom where it has its declarations.

Comment: Change the declarations (`private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1`) to `private DataGridViewDoubleBuffered dataGridView1`. I also went ahead and made my form double buffered - might be worth doing - not sure if it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Also read MSDN article:
[Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

When working with large amounts of data, the `DataGridView` control can consume a large amount of memory in overhead, unless you use it carefully. On clients with limited memory, you can avoid some of this overhead by avoiding features that have a high memory cost.

You can also manage some or all of the data maintenance and retrieval tasks yourself using virtual mode in order to customize the memory usage for your scenario. More detail you can visit dapfor. com

Answer (score 3):

i use this solution and saw bit fixed.

Reflection is used so import this too in code

```
using System.Reflection;

typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
null,this.dataGridView1,new object[] { true });
```