# Vertical text in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, vertical-text

I want to show the text in the header cells in vertical orientation. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want using custom cell painting for the header.

In answer to your comment asking for a way to align the text with the bottom of the cell, I've added comments to my code. They are hopefully clear.

You need the following code (say in the Form_Load after initializing components)

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 50;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;

// Here we attach an event handler to the cell painting event
dataGridView1.CellPainting += new DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellPainting);
```

Next you need something like the following code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    // check that we are in a header cell!
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
        Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, true);
        Size titleSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font);
        if (this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight < titleSize.Width)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = titleSize.Width;
        }

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, titleSize.Width);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90.0F);

        // This is the key line for bottom alignment - we adjust the PointF based on the 
        // ColumnHeadersHeight minus the current text width. ColumnHeadersHeight is the
        // maximum of all the columns since we paint cells twice - though this fact
        // may not be true in all usages!   
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(rect.Y - (dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight - titleSize.Width) , rect.X));

        // The old line for comparison
        //e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(rect.Y, rect.X));


        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90.0F);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -titleSize.Width);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, my usual caveat with changing the standard behaviour of the datagridview - do check if this is a must have. The control can be made to do a lot of things but often there are unexpected side effects that can rear their heads down the track.

Comment: Thanks!! Do you now how to change this code to make the text be aligned at the bottom of the cell?

Comment: @Diego I've added code which aligns to the bottom of the cell, though again, do test this thoroughly, since it uses the fact that cell painting fires twice for the headers, which might not always be true.

Comment: @DavidHall is that a way to make all cells vertically shown? not only column header. all cells shown vertically.

Comment: @aliboy38 please ask that as a separate question, perhaps with a link to this question as a comment so others can give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to use this.  I should just add 2 notes: 1 - Use e.CellBounds instead of this.dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(...).  The reason is that it is faster, and also for some reason I get visual artifacts when I access dataGridView1!  2 - To improve performance, enable double buffering (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255148/how-to-improve-painting-performance-of-datagridview)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler and more effective renderer

Attach event either through designer, or with this line of code

```
dataGridView1.CellPainting += new DataGridView1_CellPainting(dataGridView1_CellPainting);
```

Event handler to draw rotated text

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
    // Vertical text from column 0, or adjust below, if first column(s) to be skipped
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0) {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.CellBounds.Left , e.CellBounds.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(270);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.FormattedValue.ToString(),e.CellStyle.Font,Brushes.Black,5,5);
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataGrid d = new DataGrid();
d.Columns[0].HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
```

If you are looking for gridview then you case like this :-

```
GridView gv = new GridView ();
gv.Columns[0].ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
```

If you are looking for datagridview then you case like this :-
    Create an object of datagridview.

```
gv.Columns["ColumnName"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

Comment: @TechGiant: The second line for a DataGridView throws 2 errors:
'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' does not contain a definition for 'ItemStyle' and no extension method 'ItemStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
and: The name 'VerticalAlign' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Diego - for datagridview i have written last line . Try the last line that will give your result

Comment: @TechGiant: Also doen't compile: Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Columns' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Hey now try the last line actually need to use like gv.Columns["ColumnName"] not gv.Columns("ColumnName")..I have tried that works....

Comment: @Diego- May i know why you want to make header text vertical ?

Comment: Because the designer said so :(

Comment: Buddy try the above post... i have run the code and headers come as you want ...... :)

Answer (score -1):

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
   {
           if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
           {
               e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
               Rectangle rect =
this.dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, true);
               Size titleSize =
TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font);
               if (this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight <
titleSize.Width)
                   this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight =
titleSize.Width;

               e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, titleSize.Width);
               e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-90.0F);

               e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), this.Font,
Brushes.Orange, new PointF(rect.Y, rect.X));

               e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90.0F);
               e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -titleSize.Width);
               e.Handled = true;
           }
  }

In addition, you could set the AutoSizeColumnsMode property of the
DataGridView to AllCellsExceptHeader in order to make the DataGridView
compact.
```