# what is the fastest during refresh?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows forms application that is displaying columns of data. I have created it using a label which is annoyingly unorganized and blinky when I am updating during a loop. What is the fastest rendering grid that I can use for a windows forms application?

Comment: Show some code. Sounds like you tried to build a grid control yourself? For example, have you tried using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx ?

Comment: FYI, StackOverflow isn't really about recommending particular 3rd party controls or components (ie: "What is the fastest rendering grid that I can use for a windows forms application?") as that is somewhat subjective and subject to bias. I'd work on fixing your choice of approach first (drop the labels and use a grid or multiline text box or something that results in less controls and therefore less windows handles and less graphics contexts and painting operations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `DataGridView`, I've found that disabling Visual Styles on the control massively speeds up rendering.

There are other ways you can speed it up besides that, you can also enable double-buffering so you don't see the flickering (though it does reduce the framerate). See [How to improve painting performance of DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255148/how-to-improve-painting-performance-of-datagridview)