# DataGridView acting weird... not redrawing leaving weird artifacts behind

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have WinForms application that uses a DataGridView. I have one of the cells background/text colour changing depending on another cells (in the same row) values. I seem to be running into problems where the cells look like garbage when the screen sizes, moves or whatever.

This is what the problem looks like:

[image]

This is the code I use to change the column colours.

```
public static void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // this is used to colorize the cells..
    try
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        string currentColumnName = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].OwningColumn.Name;

        if (dgv.Columns.Contains(currentColumnName + "_TEXT_COLR"))
        {
            string colourString = dgv[currentColumnName + "_TEXT_COLR", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colourString);
        }
        else
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        if (dgv.Columns.Contains(currentColumnName + "_BACK_COLR"))
        {
            string colourString = dgv[currentColumnName + "_BACK_COLR", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colourString);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            else
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }                

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ?
    }

}
```

I've tried refreshing the control and the form... no luck.

Anyone?

Comment: What did you try?  Calling `Invalidate()` on the grid?  Perhaps even `Refresh()` if it must be _immediate_?

Comment: Yes I have tried both methods on the ResizeEnd event of the containing form, doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try getting rid of the Try...Catch and then fix your null problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255148/how-to-improve-painting-performance-of-datagridview):

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
{
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
}
```

Works great!!

Comment: `DoubleBuffered` is typically a property...can't you just set it in the appropriate constructor, or even in designer?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Only on forms.  It's protected otherwise, so you either inherit from it, or use reflection.

Comment: @LarsTech Not true.  That property is handed down from `Control`.  You can access it on a `Panel` for instance.

Comment: @DonBoitnott First time I ever set a property this way. Another example was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens

Comment: @DonBoitnott No, you can't.  It's `protected virtual bool` in the Control source code.

Comment: @carny666 That last example is making your own class called `CustomDataGridView` which inherits from the stock `DataGrid View`.  And then _setting the property_, as I first suggested.  Probably the cleanest alternative, IMO.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Try what?  Putting a panel control on a form?  No DoubleBuffered property: `Cannot access protected member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoubleBuffered'`

Comment: @LarsTech I see it now.  I rarely deal in stock controls, so all the code I have in front of me are _inherited_, so access to `DoubleBuffered` is available.  My mistake.