# Stop refreshing datagridview when scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, datagridview, refresh

I have a lot of results displayed in DataGridView (rows and columns). When I scroll up and down or left and right the datagridview is refreshing and the cells are displayed each time. This is annoying because of refreshing and in specially when you have some operations in `DataGridViewControl_CellFormatting` event.
How can I stop refreshing when I'm scrolling in dataGridView? 
I'm using WinForms in C#

Comment: I filled a datagridview with 2000 items to test this for you but I'm having trouble reproducing your issue. With refresh I take it you mean its flickering? Have you tried dubblebuffered? I have posted an answer including that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Every time I scroll into datagridview the grid is flickering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
{
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
}
```

This is to enable doublebuffered on a Data grid view. I got this from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255148/how-to-improve-painting-performance-of-datagridview)

Comment: Good find, although I would agree with cody: _The method you posted uses reflection to change a non-public property on a DataGridView control. This is an acceptable solution, but it's probably cleaner just to inherit off of the existing DataGridView control and create your own custom control with the "DoubleBuffered" style set._