# DataGridView double buffered where to invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Just a simple question. I found how to speed up `datagridview` by enabling `Double buffering` hided feature.
Is it fine if i place that code into `Form's load event` when `datagridview` is located?

```
typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember(
                "DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                null,
                grid,
                new object[] { true });
```

[Code taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255148/how-to-improve-painting-performance-of-datagridview)

Comment: This should not matter at all; when set it'll stick until unset.

Comment: @TaW i assume this code has to be added to every form where datagridviews are used, am i right?

Comment: Either that or use a DGV subclass with DoubleBuffering enabled in its constructor(s).. Not that one always needs it, though: esp. with only a few rows/columns it is not necessary..But, [when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893708/how-to-prevent-datagridview-from-flickering-when-scrolling-horizontally/41894210#41894210) you do it is nice

Comment: @TaW but how can i use that class: class DBDataGridView : DataGridView. I already has my datagridview on form. How to do that?

Comment: Well one can always edit the Designer.cs file __if__ one does it right. There are 2 (or 3?) spots in it where the control is defined as a DGV; change them to be you DBDGV class and all ought to be well. Make sure to properly backup before editing the desinger.cs file !!!

Comment: @TaW i put that peace of code to static method in external static class helper: public static void TurnOnDoubleBufferec(DataGridView grid) .. and call this static method from each form i need

Comment: Are you really speeding up, or just preventing code from hanging?  What I usually do when I get a winform that hangs is put code into a backgroundworker so form doesn't lock up.  Sounds like you have same issue with form locking.

Comment: @jdw: This is really about scrolling large DGVs. You can see the effect in the link in my comment above..