# How do I stop the datagridview from violently repainting when a user clicks on a cell that was not initially visible?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is horizontally large. A good portion of it must be scrolled to in order for the user to see it. Curiously, whenever someone *first* clicks on a cell that wasn't in the group of 'originally visible cells', the datagridview decides to repaint itself. This might not have been a huge problem, but for this datagridview the repainting is really slow and noticeable.

The second click and all subsequent clicks on a particular cell will not cause the repaint.

Does anyone know how to calm the datagridview down?

Thanks!

Comment: I should add this doesn't happen if you scroll down to a cell with the vertical scroll bar, and click on it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I just had to add DoubleBuffered = true to the constructor of my subclassed Datagridview.

Thanks to this guy:

[Horrible redraw performance of the DataGridView on one of my two screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)