# Generating a clickable grid by C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying to draw a pretty large clickable grid. I tried datagridviews but a large one took a fairly long time to generate, I mean not all the cells immediately appeared. Afterwards, I tried drawing a pretty large number of clickable rectangles and adding them to the form but they took a similarly long time to be generated.
Here is the class I created for drawing a rectangle:

```
  internal sealed class Box : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(Width - 1, Height - 1)));
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked The Box!");
    }
}}
```

I wonder if there is a faster way to generate a clickable grid. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many controls take time to render. A DGV should be by far the best option. You may need to use a [DoubleBuffered subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)!  ((btw: setting a Border would be better than drawing it if it is just a single line)) - Also when asking such a question I recommend telling us about the actual numbers!

Comment: I can't tell from the small code you posted, but keep in mind that you should only draw what would only be visible to the actual user. A grid isn't drawing for each row in the collection, just the rows that should be displayed at that paint cycle.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a single control that paints the grid of boxes, and handles the clicks based on the relative position of where it was clicked.

Comment: Set property DoubleBuffered=true to increase the performance of drawing...

Comment: I am not sure simple rectangles will result in a "clickable grid".  You might need some object there to register the clicks internally.