# Slow UI rendering in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I'm making a relatively rudimentary `WinForms` user control with a number of buttons, each representing a table from a database.

The data from each table is loaded into a corresponding `DataGridView` after the `InitializeComponent` method is called.

When one of the aforementioned buttons is clicked, its corresponding `DataGridView`, and those representing tables linked to the main one through FKs become visible and then a `BackgroundWorker` gradually increases them to their desired sizes and shifts controls to appropriate locations over a short period of time.

```
public uc1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PopulateTables();

    tableResizer.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    tableResizer.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    tableResizer.DoWork += tableResizer_DoWork;
    tableResizer.ProgressChanged += tableResizer_ProgressChanged;
    tableResizer.RunWorkerCompleted += tableResizer_RunWorkerCompleted;

    dgv5.SelectionChanged += show5Relations;
}

private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainTable = 5;
    btn5.Visible = false;
    btn4.Visible = false;
    btn3.Visible = false;
    btn2.Visible = false;
    dgv5.Visible = true;
    dgv4.Visible = true;
    dgv3.Visible = true;
    dgv2.Visible = true;
    lbl6.Visible = false;
    lbl7.Visible = false;
    lbl1.Visible = false;
    tableResizer.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void tableResizer_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int expansion = 0;
    while (expansion < 30)
    {
        tableResizer.ReportProgress(mainTable);
        expansion++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(16);
    }
}

private void tableResizer_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage == 5)
    {
        dgv5.Size = new Size(dgv5.Size.Width + (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 30), dgv5.Size.Height + (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 30));
        dgv5.Location = new Point(dgv5.Location.X - (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 60), dgv5.Location.Y - (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 60));

        dgv4.Size = new Size(dgv4.Size.Width + (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 30), dgv4.Size.Height + (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 50));
        dgv4.Location = new Point(dgv4.Location.X - (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 40), dgv4.Location.Y - (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 120));

        dgv3.Size = new Size(dgv3.Size.Width + (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 30), dgv3.Size.Height + (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 50));
        dgv3.Location = new Point(dgv3.Location.X - (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 40), dgv3.Location.Y - (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 120));

        dgv2.Size = new Size(dgv2.Size.Width + (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 30), dgv2.Size.Height + (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 50));
        dgv2.Location = new Point(dgv2.Location.X - (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 40), dgv2.Location.Y - (((this.Height / 24) * 10) / 120));

        btn1.Location = new Point(btn1.Location.X - (((this.Width / 26) * 10) / 130), btn1.Location.Y);
    }
}

private void tableResizer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainTable == 5)
    {
        btn7.Visible = true;
        btn6.Visible = true;
        btn1.Visible = true;
        lbl5.Visible = true;
        lbl5.Location = new Point(dgv5.Location.X, dgv5.Location.Y - lbl5.Size.Height);
        lbl4.Visible = true;
        lbl4.Location = new Point(dgv4.Location.X, dgv4.Location.Y - lbl4.Size.Height);
        lbl3.Visible = true;
        lbl3.Location = new Point(dgv3.Location.X, dgv3.Location.Y - lbl3.Size.Height);
        lbl2.Visible = true;
        lbl2.Location = new Point(dgv2.Location.X, dgv2.Location.Y - lbl1.Size.Height);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the UI is not being rendered fast enough when the `tableResizer` is doing its work, and as a result, one of the `DataGridViews` is not fully visible until the work is finished.

Increasing the length of the Sleep in the `DoWork` method only fixes this issue when it is at 60ms, at which point the rendering is too choppy to be acceptable. Anything more than 30ms will not do.

I am relatively new to multithreading and arguably C# in general, so I am pretty sure there are more efficient ways to go about this.

What should I do to ensure smooth rendering?

Comment: If all you're using a `BackgroundWorker` for is animation then use a `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the solution to my problem. Though I had tried setting `DoubleBuffered` to true for the user control before, it did not help. The problem was that `DataGridViews` have it turned off by default and since it is a protected property it cannot be set to true.

Upon further investigation of this issue (which I should have done sooner, my apologies), I discovered this answered question:
[Horrible redraw performance of the DataGridView on one of my two screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118528/horrible-redraw-performance-of-the-datagridview-on-one-of-my-two-screens)

The solution is very simple. Create a class which inherits from the default `DataGridView` and assign its `DoubleBuffered` property to true.

```
class CustomDataGridView: DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGridView()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    } 
}
```